# Mi consulta solo toma mi where de busqueda mysqli y php

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo el siguiente problema.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM trabajos 
";

if($_POST['query'] != '')
{
  $query .= '
  WHERE equipo_kal LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'% and estado_kal="Finalizado" "
  ';
}
```

El problema es que mi where solo toma el primer valor del where equipo_kal y el AND que sigue no toma eso.

Que error estoy cometiendo?

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Saludos.

Pregunta editada: coloco todo el código completo es que esta consulta hago un paginador:

```
$limit = '3';
$page = 1;
if($_POST['page'] > 1)
{
  $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
  $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
  $start = 0;
}

$query = "
SELECT * FROM trabajos 
";

if($_POST['query'] != '')
{
  $query .= '
  WHERE equipo_kal LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%" AND estado_kal="Finalizado"
  ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY reporte_kal DESC ';

$filter_query = $query . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';
```

El AND en mayúscula aun sigue fin funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no se esta concatenando bien la consulta

Despues del segundo % te hace falta una comilla doble y después de Finalizado te sobra una

```
$query .= '
  WHERE equipo_kal LIKE "%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']).'%" AND estado_kal="Finalizado"';
```

Te sugiero utilices mayusculas para las palabras reservadas de sql como el AND

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola @Pillo acabo de editar mi pregunta.

Comment: Has probado en poner toda la condicion dentro de parentesis ?

Comment: Podrías poner después del la linea $filter_query  una linea con error_log($filter_query); y compartirnos lo que te envío a la consola? Esto es para ver como se forma la consulta y si se están cumpliendo todas las condiciones de tu consulta